# Insert cookie if value is not present

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to insert cookie. The logic is simple as:

- Check if the value is present .
- If not, insert new value with comma separated form.

I have tried some code  but I could not able to get a correct result.

In this code a new value should be inserted, which is happening but not getting old value.

**Edited Code 2**

```
        $current_value = '';
 if(!isset($_COOKIE['blog_id_cookie'])){
     setcookie('blog_id_cookie', $id);
     $current_value[] = $_COOKIE['blog_id_cookie'];
 } else {
     $current_value = explode(',', $_COOKIE['blog_id_cookie']);
 } 
 if(!in_array($id, $current_value)){
     $current_value[] = $id;
     $cookie_name  = "blog_id_cookie";
     setcookie($cookie_name, implode(',', $current_valu));
 }
```

Comment: So what is not working now? `$current_value` will be set only if the cookie is not set.

Comment: i am getting only one value ex:   ',19'

Answer (score 0):

With that code `$current_value` will be defined only if the cookies is not set. Set `$current_value` in the else part. Concatenate the `cookie` instead of `$current_value`. Try with -

**Update**

```
 $current_value = '';
 if(!isset($_COOKIE['blog_id_cookie'])){
     setcookie('blog_id_cookie', $id);
     $current_value[] = $_COOKIE['blog_id_cookie'];
 } else {
     $current_value = explode(',', $_COOKIE['blog_id_cookie']);
 } 
 if(!in_array($id, $current_value)){
     $current_value[] = $id;
     $cookie_name  = "blog_id_cookie";
     setcookie($cookie_name, implode(',', $current_value));
 }
```

Comment: Then what o/p do you need?

Comment: a new value is inserted in my code when i visit detail page of blog,it is happening ,if i visit 22 blog 22 will be inserted ,then if i visit 15 blog 15 should be inserted along with 22 o/p should be 22,15

Comment: in the present code only one value is inserting at a time and same value is repeating

Comment: @ sgt BOSE  i have edited code as per your suggestion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76864/discussion-between-abhi-ahere-and-sgt-bose).

Comment: Not getting result , ony new value is inserting but not getting old and new value

Comment: I have added the code pls check present o/p ',22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22'

Comment: i am getting the values in different manner example: if i visit detail of 22 id page i am getting ',22' if i visit detail of 19 id page i am getting ',19' seperately

Comment: It should not happen o/p should be only one '22,19,15' etc